# Hack to maintain horizontal element position when scroll bar apears

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, scrollbar

My pages are all using the typical fixed-width-margin-left-right-auto layout.

```
.container{
     width:900px;
     margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here comes the little problem. Some of those pages are higher than a window, which means they should show the vertical scroll bar on right side. Switching between those pages and others, the main container will move a little bit ( half-width of v-scrollbar ). I know it's because width of parent element (body) changed.

But does any know if there be a library or existing hack to suppress this behaviour? (except body{overflow-y:scroll;})

reply to @Mateusz:
Thanks Matousz, a good idea. I tried the following code

```
console.log($('body')[0].offsetHeight+' '+$('body')[0].scrollHeight+' '+$('html'[0].offsetHeight+' '+$('html')[0].scrollHeight);
```

the test results are

```
           doc smaller than win              doc larger than win
firefox    1012 1012 1008 1362               1012 1012 1008 1007
chrome/ie  549 1525 545 545                    549 545 545 545
```

so they got different behaviours, and the comparing threadshods are different  (1 and 4).

Comment: As far as I know and I have experienced the chance of those 2 CSS properties stopping the display of the scrollbar is null. Your problem is elsewhere. After you can not remove default browser behaviour, but you can update your DOM accordingly by detecting the amount it has moved from and put it back where it was. Not aware of any library providing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare element.offsetHeight and element.scrollHeight.  And change your position of your container depending on this.

Comment: Man that's really cool. But here the is a really crappy flow between browsers. I better edit reply into the question .